# Looking for books on the Benoni

Tags: opening, modern-benoni

I am looking for books in the Benoni where this sequence of moves is played, so:

```
 [fen ""]

1.d4 Nf6 2.c4 c5 3.d5 e6 4. Nc3 exd5 5. cxd5 d6
```

And black's plan after that is g6.

Also if possible that it can be electronically downloaded/bought.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on what you are looking for, there are a few interesting books. If you are looking for a book to start to learn the opening, I suggest you take a look at:

- [Starting out: Modern Benoni](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1857443667) by Endre Dr. Vegh.

In such case, you may also want to round up your repertoire with the companion book:

- [Starting out: Benoni Systems](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1857443799) by Alex Raetsky.

Which provides a more complete coverage of some similar lines (but not exactly the same, although some intersection is inevitable) that are not exactly achieved through the main move order.

If you already know how to play or what you want to play and are looking only for ideas, then the Dangerous Weapons book is definitely what you may want to check:

- [Dangerous Weapons: The Benoni and Benko](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1857445716) by several authors.

Last but not least, if you are already a well versed player on the Modern Benoni and just want to keep up with some theoretical developments in the last years, and what trends are being followed, I strongly suggest the book:

- [Chess Developments: The Modern Benoni](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/185744681X) by Richard Pallister.

My experience with the Chess Development series arises from the [Dragon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1857446755) and [Grunfeld](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1857446895) books, which definitely are worth the money if that is what you are looking for.

I obviously have not fully read them all. I have read a couple of chapters of the first three books, and the last one comes from my experience with the series as a whole.

Comment: I would think that downloading these books for free when they are sold is technically illegal, so I would suggest removing those links you have posted. Despite the last comment.

Comment: Thank you for the links, and it is only illegal to download them, not to tell the people where. Please leave the links for future reference. I will buy the book I like the most when I go outstate.

Comment: @ETD, could you please refer me to somewhere where I could see what is allowed and what not when posting downloading links to copyrighted material? I don't want to make the same mistake twice.

Comment: pablo, AFAIK such kinds of links are prohibited throughout the SE network. See posts like [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/195834/190126) and [this other one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/208629/190126) from the network-wide Meta StackExchange site.

Answer (score 2):

[Grandmaster Repertoire: The Modern Benoni](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1907982590) by Marian Petrov comes highly recommended, ideas are explained and there are many variations to choose from, as is charateristic of the GM repertoire series.

Answer (score 0):

May I refer 'The Modern Benoni' by GM Norwood. Its light weight compared to others referred here, but is a good book if you are staring out.

Then there's 'The Complete Benoni' by Lev Psakhis